# Optimal xcache settings for VPS 512mb ram

Tags: performance, php-fpm, xcache

I use ubuntu 11.10, apache2 with varnish, php5-fpm and xcache.
I have 512mb ram with 4 cpus. linux kernel version 3.

What are the optimal xcache settings?

Should I make also some changes and settings also at my kernel/system to allow it have more memory size than the default 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quick comments (I have just been reading a bit about it and tweaking my own set up).

Set xcache.count to the number of CPU *cores* (eg, if your 4 CPUs are dual-core, then use *8* as the value)

Only worry about **cache.var_size** if you are using the variable cache (via **xcache_get()**, etc; check the [api doc](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/XcacheApi) )

Otherwise, I have xcache.size set to 64M and it's *enough*.
Using the [admin/status page](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallAdministration) you might be able to see that you have too many cache misses (missed hits) and then you could increase xcache.size.